# modul left multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules, ideals

Hi im studying noncommutative algebra and have a question about left multiplication as a homomorphism of R-Leftmodules. As far as I understand, if M is a Left Ideal it is a R-Leftmodul and because of associativity for $a,b \in R , m \in I$
$$ l_a(mb)=a(mc)=(am)c=l_a(m)c  $$ so left multiplication ist right-linear. But how do i even know that $mb \in I$? Can i generalize this for $$ M \not\subset R $$ or M not an Ideal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that $mb\notin I$, unless $I$ is a right ideal too.

If $M$ is a left ideal, $m\mapsto mr$ is a left $R$ linear map from $I\to R$ whose image might not be contained in $I$.

Comment: Thanks that helped a lot.
But  can I say if $S \subset R $ is a subring. And $M\subset R$ is a left R-Modul and a right S-Modul? Then $l_b $ is S right linear. But to show this M needs to be in R so I can use associativity. Is that right?

Comment: @MaximilianBöhmermann I don’t understand the question in your comment.  Several things seem nonsensical. Please separate your hypotheses from your conclusions.

Comment: Sorry. My Question is: Is the following "theorem" true: R is a ring and S $\subset R$ is a subring. $I\subset R$ is an  Leftideal that is a S-Rightmodul then $l_b$ is S-right linear.

Comment: @MaximilianBöhmermann yes, $\ell_b$ would be a right S linear endomorphism of $I$.

Comment: Assuming the S module action is the natural one using multiplication in R